# I can’t attach a Rabbit MQ client to Locust user

Tags: rabbitmq, locust, kombu

I am trying to run a load test that injects messages to rabbit mq, but I can get locust user class to get the custom client I created loaded. Has someone managed to do this?

```
import os
from locust import HttpUser, task, TaskSet, run_single_user
from kombu import Connection, Exchange, Queue


class KombuClient:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.connection = Connection(
            hostname=os.getenv(
                "LOCUST_AMQP_CONFIG", "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"
            ),
        )
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()

    def send_message(self, message):
        exchange = Exchange(
            name=os.getenv("LOCUST_AMQP_EXCHANGE", "test_exchange"),
            type="direct",
        )
        queue = Queue(
            name=os.getenv("LOCUST_AMQP_QUEUE", "test_queue"),
            exchange=exchange,
            routing_key=os.getenv("LOCUST_AMQP_KEY", "test_key"),
        )
        queue.maybe_bind(self.connection)
        queue.declare()

        producer = self.connection.Producer(
            exchange=exchange,
            routing_key=os.getenv("LOCUST_AMQP_KEY", "test_key"),
        )
        producer.publish(message)
        print("INFO: Sent message: '{}'".format(message))

    def close_connection(self):
        self.connection.release()

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    @task
    def send_hello_message(self):
        I make it work by, instead of the line below but that is not 100% correct--> KombuClient().send_message("Hello World!")
        self.client.send_message("Hello World!")


class RabbitMQUser(HttpUser):
    host = "http://localhost"
    tasks = [UserBehavior]
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 9000
    client = KombuClient
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_single_user(RabbitMQUser)
```

In general I can inject the messages but Locust does not recognize the transaction and does not shows any user running.

I have tried to inspect the Locust code to see what the client expected class is, but I haven’t found any useful information.

I guess the API changed as I am using Locust 2.15.1 and there is no HttpClient class no more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is [covered in the Locust FAQ](https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ#locust-web-ui-doesnt-show-my-tasks-running-says-0-rps) and examples can be found [in the docs](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html). What you need to do is fire the `request` event with all your request info and stats. You're using `HttpUser` but overriding the `client` so you're making it just a normal `User` which doesn't know about what you're doing and you need to tell it what to record and when.

Example taken from the docs for the gRPC scenario:

```
self.environment.events.request.fire(
        request_type="grpc",
        name=call_details.method,
        response_time=(time.perf_counter() - start_perf_counter) * 1000,
        response_length=response_length,
        response=response,
        context=None,
        exception=exception,
    )
```

Call this with your own stats. See the linked doc page for explanations as to what the parameters are meant to be, but since you're doing a custom user you can make them be and mean whatever you want.

Comment: Yes, this is part of the problem. I also was assigning the client incorrectly. Now it is done through the init class. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code, I am still missing adding the changes @Solowalker suggested, but if you put all together you can have the whole answer. I will try to update the code once all is working.

```
import os
from locust import task, TaskSet, User, run_single_user
from locust.clients import HttpSession
from kombu import Connection, Exchange, Queue


class KombuClient(HttpSession):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.connection = Connection(
            hostname=os.getenv(
                "LOCUST_AMQP_CONFIG", "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"
            ),
        )
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()

    def send_message(self, message):
        exchange = Exchange(
            name=os.getenv("LOCUST_AMQP_EXCHANGE", "test_exchange"),
            type="direct",
        )
        queue = Queue(
            name=os.getenv("LOCUST_AMQP_QUEUE", "test_queue"),
            exchange=exchange,
            routing_key=os.getenv("LOCUST_AMQP_KEY", "test_key"),
        )
        queue.maybe_bind(self.connection)
        queue.declare()

        producer = self.connection.Producer(
            exchange=exchange,
            routing_key=os.getenv("LOCUST_AMQP_KEY", "test_key"),
        )
        producer.publish(message)
        print("INFO: Sent message: '{}'".format(message))

    def close_connection(self):
        self.connection.release()


class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    @task
    def send_hello_message(self):
        self.client.send_message(message="Hello World!")


class RabbitMQUser(User):
    host = "http://localhost"
    tasks = [UserBehavior]
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 9000
    abstract = True

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super().__init__(environment)
        self.client = KombuClient(self.host, user=self, request_event=environment.events.request)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_single_user(RabbitMQUser)
```